# What can I do if there is no shadow method found for some methods with robolectric?

Tags: android, testing, shadow, robolectric

I'm using [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) to test android code, and found there are some  tests failed because there are some methods don't have shadow method.

In my logic code, I retrieved a bitmap from another activity:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromResult(data);
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

And later in another method, I get the bitmap from the `imageView`, and save it to file:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
// save to file
bitmap.compress(...);
```

But the last line throws NullPointerException when testing.

I debugged into the code, and found when the test code running with robolectric, the `drawable` is a `ShadowBitmapDrawable` contains a `null` bitmap. So `drawable.getBitmap()` return a `null` which causes the exception.

Then I enabled logging in my test code:

```
Robolectric.logMissingInvokedShadowMethods();
```

Found one line in console which I think causes my test code failed:

```
No Shadow method found for BitmapDrawable.<init>(android.content.res.Resources, android.graphics.Bitmap)
```

What can I do now? Is it possible to add a shadow method to fix it and how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Clone the source from github: https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/

Add a shadow method to `ShadowBitmapDrawable.java`:

```
public void __constructor__(android.content.res.Resources res, Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Then compile it and package it to a jar. It's fixed.